# Convert xmlWriter.WriteElementString value to date and time

Tags: c#, xml

I am using c# to  write this value that is coming from SQL into an XML file. It is datatype datetime in the SQL table.

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("DDATE", reader[7].ToString());
```

How do I convert it to date and time in this format?

2011-11-21T00:00:00

Keep on getting error: cannot convert sytem.datetime to string when I try:

```
DateTime.ParseExact
```

Comment: What is `reader`? Is it a SqlDataReader?

Comment: what's the value of `reader[7]`?

Comment: Yes reader is SqlDataReader. Currently the value  is 3/1/2019 12:00:00 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reader.GetDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the DateTime from the database.  Then, since `WriteElementString` takes string arguments just call `.ToString()`:

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("DDATE", reader.GetDateTime(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
```

If you always want the time component to be `00:00:00` just use `dateTime.Date`.

```
reader.GetDateTime(7).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))
```